# Mapbox AutofillAddress Returning Null Using react-map-gl & search-js-react

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I am working on my first React project and am a bit confused by some of the Mapbox Documentation.

I am looking to use the AddressAutofill from Mapbox-Search-JS to allow users to quickly autofill address information on a form. On submit, I then wanted to take that address and convert it into longitude and latitude (currently using Google Maps API for this).

Upon submitting the form, all of the inputs submit correctly except the 'address-line1' input which  returns null. This also happens to be the input that is wrapped in the AddressAutofill element. Is there an extra step somewhere here that I'm missing in the interaction between the user selecting the autofilled address from the list and the actual value of the input?

I'm a new dev-in-progress, so I apologize if anything above is not explained as well as it could! I'm happy to try to answer any questions if more clarification is needed! Thanks in advance!

I've tried reviewing some of the Mapbox Docs, specifically, the Mapbox-Search-JS' React Reference for the Address Autofill, but don't quite understand what I'm supposed to do with some of the AddressAutofillProps that are listed. Everything I tried to use just returned errors and there aren't a ton of examples regarding how some of these props are used. Any clarification on some of this would be helpful!

I've also tried wrapping the input in a plain div and didn't have any issues, so it definitely seems like I'm missing something else with the AutofillAddress element.

Form Component

```
import { Form } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AddressAutofill } from '@mapbox/search-js-react';

import classes from './AddVenueForm.module.css';

const AddVenueForm = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Add Venue</h1>
      <div className={classes.formContainer}>
        <Form method='post' className={classes.addVenueForm}>
          <label htmlFor='name'>
            Venue Name
            <input type='text' id='name' name='name' />
          </label>
          <label htmlFor='address'>
            Street Address
            <AddressAutofill accessToken='###'>
              <input
                type='text'
                id='address'
                name='address'
                autoComplete='address-line1'
              />
            </AddressAutofill>
          </label>
          <label htmlFor='name'>
            City
            <input
              type='text'
              id='city'
              name='city'
              autoComplete='address-level2'
            />
          </label>
          <label htmlFor='name'>
            State
            <input
              type='text'
              id='state'
              name='state'
              autoComplete='address-level1'
            />
          </label>
          <button
            type='submit'
            className={classes.formSubmit}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddVenueForm;
```

Action Handler Function (just trying to log the data for now)

```
export async function action({ request }) {
  const formData = await request.formData();

  const name = formData.get('name');
  const address = formData.get('address');
  const city = formData.get('city');
  const state = formData.get('state');

  const venueData = {
    name,
    address,
    city,
    state,
  };

  console.log(formData);

  return venueData;
}
```